# Given a Type and a String, can you try to convert the String to that Type without interogating the Type?

Tags: c#, parsing, types, casting

I have a `List<Type>` that represent a signature for a text based command from a custom scripting language. I am trying to determine how to parse a `String[]` to a `List<object>` where the object types correlate to the `List<Type>`. Basically given a `Type t` I would like to try to cast a `String s` to that `Type`.

So far I have this

```
Type t = ...;
String s = ...;
if(Convert.ChangeType(s, t) != null)
{

}
```

Which I doubt is correct after thinking about [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) more. It is meant to simply change the type of the given object, not "parse" it. Seeing as you can't simply do `(double)"ImAString"` I would assume this method would be used to convert between object types that are "directly" castable.

Is there any general solution to this? Or is the only way to do this to create a large `switch` on the given `Type` and parse within each case(Most likely missing Types in the switch in the future)?

**EDIT:** Further, the return type of `ChangeType` is object. I assume that if I were to do a `retObjectFromChange is double` would be true (assuming I changed the type to a double)?

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType()` seems like one correct approach.  You can convert a string to a double just fine, but an exception may be thrown if the conversion fails.  ie: `"1.001"` would work fine while `"ImAString"` would throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Convert.ChangeType()` will parse strings to numbers when possible, throwing an exception on strings that aren't valid numbers.

Note: If you are going to convert between your own custom types a lot, you may want to use a `TypeConverter` instead.  (`TypeConverter` will work better when converting both to-from primitive types like `string`.)

See:
[Convert System.String generically to any complex type using "Convert.ChangeType()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401851/convert-system-string-generically-to-any-complex-type-using-convert-changetype)

EDIT:
Yes, `Convert.ChangeType("1.02", typeof(double)) is double` should evaluate to true assuming no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: I currently planned on using only primitive types and possibly an `enum` or two. I assume from the answer that these would work just fine. // From the linked question, specifically our savior Jon Skeet's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5401888/2985796) would the solution to convert to more complex types be to implement the `IConvertable` interface within those types? // I also made a small edit to the question that I assume is a simple answer if you could address it too?

Comment: The problem with `IConvertable` is that it can be difficult to convert from string to Foo even while it's easy to convert from Foo to string.  (If that makes sense)

Comment: Assuming I implemented the class that implements `IConvertable` it should be "easy". I just have to make sure the definition of the class object as a string is exact, albeit it might grow to some very ignorant looking string. Is that what you mean by not easy?

Comment: @KDecker I was referring to Jon Skeet's answer that it "won't work the other way around".  You can convert Foo to String just fine, but if you have a String it's non-trivial to extend String to convert to Foo using `ChangeType()`.  On the other hand `TypeConverter` will happily convert String to Foo since you're the one implementing the whole thing.  Foo and Bar (if you wrote both) will happily go both ways even with just `IConvertable`.

Answer (score 2):

This is my current implementation. I found Guid, DateTime, enums, and nullables to be my edge cases. And I put in logic to handle empty strings and null values. I put in specific handling for some of the primitives because I found the TypeConverter to be slow in comparison for these, and they were my general case.

```
    public object GetValue(string readerValue, Type conversionType)
    {
        // if the type is a string, just return the value with no conversion
        if (conversionType == typeof(string) || conversionType == typeof(object))
        {
            return readerValue;
        }

        // if the field has a value try to cast it
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readerValue))
        {
            readerValue = readerValue.Trim();

            if (conversionType.IsEnum)
            {
                return Enum.Parse(conversionType, readerValue);
            }
            else
            {
                Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(conversionType) ?? conversionType;

                if (underlyingType == typeof(int))
                {
                    return int.Parse(readerValue);
                }
                else if (underlyingType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    return bool.Parse(readerValue);
                }
                else if (underlyingType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    return DateTime.Parse(readerValue);
                }
                else if (underlyingType == typeof(double))
                {
                    return double.Parse(readerValue);
                }
                else if (underlyingType == typeof(long))
                {
                    return long.Parse(readerValue);
                }
                else if (underlyingType == typeof(Guid))
                {
                    return Guid.Parse(readerValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    // GetConverter and ConvertFrom are both slow, so only use it in a fallback
                    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(underlyingType);
                    return converter.ConvertFrom(readerValue);
                }
            }
        }
        // return null for nullable generic primitives
        else if (conversionType.IsGenericType && conversionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            return null;
        }
        // return the default value for non nullable primitive types
        else if (conversionType.IsValueType)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(conversionType);
        }
        // return null for reference types
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a very complete solution.

Comment: If you find any more edge cases that I'm not handling, let me know. I'm planning on using this in a release at some point so I'd love to know about issues ahead of time.

Comment: Actually, I have some production code with practically the same method signature that works very similar to your code, also for mostly performance reasons.  I implement 2 methods for converting various objects to/from string.  This is a very practical approach.

Comment: I know this is years old but most of this code can be turned into a hashmap lookup

Answer (score 0):

one huge edge case is that this will explode if conversionType is null.
right here:
if (conversionType.IsEnum)

Also the second check is problematic, Object could just be a box for null Object o = null; for example look at this code, it'll warn but compile fine. if O is null Type is now null. I could get into it a little more but there are other reasons I wouldn't just fire away in that second case
for example

```
    Object o = null;
    Type T = o?.GetType() ?? null;
```

//Also signed vs. unsigned.
there is also a ton of reflection in this solution. here is what i'd do, build a TypeMap by using and extending TypeCode, you could easily get 25 types without reflection

```
   if (conversionType == typeof(string) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readerValue))
   {
     return conversionType;
   }
```

so now we know things, we don't want a string and we have null.
Now we have to see if we are nested,
if(typeof(conversiontype).isnested

```
  Type.GetTypeCode(conversionType);
```

in practice it's better to create a true Dictionary<int, String> so you can add your own types. Even better this returns 0 if conversion is null. you can also create a typemap dictionary on the fly and Cache it. It's got about twenty types and and as I said can be extended.

```
var TypeMap = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TypeCode)).Cast<TypeCode>().ToDictionary(t=>(int)t, f=>f.ToString());
```

after that simply get the type by calling gettype on the string.
accepts all of those strings as arguments.

```
now here's the fun part, i've got about 30 or 40 types in my hashmap however if it's not in there
try
{
Type T = Type.GetType(CustomTypeMap[TypeCode])
if(TypeCode != 0)
// see if the type is nested and repeat
//the cases I had to add to TypeCode myself were GUID, ENUM, 
}
if you want to skip a step your dictionary can look like this as well
```

```
  Dictionary<int, Type> IntToType = new Dictionary<int, Type>()
    {
        [1] = typeof(bool),
        [2] = typeof(int),
        [3]  = typeof(double),
        [4]  = typeof(string),
    };
```